# cat < file.txt Who is the responsible of reading the file?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, cat

```
cat < file.txt
```

Who is the responsible of reading the file ?

Is the shell reads the open and read the file then write its content to the standard input of the command ?

Comment: The shell is opening the file for reading, and `cat` is reading the file contents from `stdin` and then writing the output to `stdout`.

Comment: You've worn out the keyboard twice with this. Why not just `cat file.txt`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the shell command `cat <file.txt`:

1. The redirection operator `<` causes the shell to open `file.txt` for reading.
2. The shell executes the `cat` command, with its standard input connected to `file.txt`.
3. The `cat` command reads from its standard input (so `file.txt`) and copies the content to its standard output.

So the shell is the one opening the file, but the `cat` command is the one reading the data.

You can observe what is going on by listing the system calls performed by the shell and its subprocesses. On Linux:

```
$ strace -f sh -c 'cat <file.txt' >/dev/null
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "cat <file.txt"], [/* 76 vars */]) = 0
…
open("file.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
…
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
…
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fbc737539d0) = 22703
[pid 22702] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 22703] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 76 vars */]) = 0
[pid 22703] read(0, "wibble"..., 32768) = 6
[pid 22703] write(1, "wibble"..., 6) = 6
[pid 22703] read(0, "", 32768)          = 0
[pid 22703] close(0)                    = 0
[pid 22703] close(1)                    = 0
[pid 22703] close(2)                    = 0
[pid 22703] exit_group(0)               = ?
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 22703
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x11)                      = 22703
…
```

(22702 is the parent shell process, 22703 is the child `cat`)

The shell command `cat file.txt` works differently.

1. The shell executes the `cat` command, passing it one parameter, namely `file.txt`.
2. The `cat` program opens `file.txt` for reading.
3. The `cat` command reads from `file.txt` and copies the content to its standard output.

Comment: plus 1 for strace

Comment: What about cat file.txt

Comment: @faressoft added

Answer (score -1):

You're correct.  While this won't matter in many situations, if the shell and the process have different permissions it can.

If the process you're calling has elevated privileges (such as `sudo` or setuid), then it can use those privileges to open files that your shell might not be able to.

```
$ sudo cat < /etc/shadow | wc
-bash: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
      0       0       0
$ sudo cat /etc/shadow | wc
     64      64    1843
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The OP asks if the shell opens *AND READS* the file, but that is not the case. The shell in fact opens the file but does not read it.